# ASP.NET AJAX 4.0 Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, .net-4.0

I have VS 2010 and I installed ajax 1.0 but i don't have an ajax library template when I create a new web project so what do i need to do to set that up. I noticed also on some ajax web videos there a list of ajax library files in the scripts folder there's quite a few of them. where do i download them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it via microsoft's CDN the files you need:
[AJAX on MS CDN](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/CDNAjax4.ashx).

Also let me add, with ScriptManager in 4.0 you can set the property EnableCdn="true" which will get all ajax framework js files for you. Also look at the  AjaxFrameworkMode property which will be of help as well.

Answer (score 1):

Donload the [toolkit](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/), and take a look et [How to get started](http://www.asp.net/ajax/videos/how-do-i-get-started-with-aspnet-ajax)

**Edit**:

Please refer this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc546561.aspx

http://blogs.visoftinc.com/archive/2009/04/28/ASP.NET-4.0-AJAX-Preview-4-Client-Templates.aspx
http://forums.asp.net/p/1551382/3804608.aspx

Comment: to me it's just all code and I don't understand much of it cos it's all new. How do i set up vs 2010 to have an ajax enabled web app and where do you get all the js script libraries from

Comment: cannot download the files from this link http://blogs.visoftinc.com/archive/2009/04/28/ASP.NET-4.0-AJAX-Preview-4-Client-Templates.aspx

Comment: tried to download the Asp.Net_Ajax_Preview_4.zip but it's not there at codeplex

Comment: can you email me the file I need

Comment: Ok, download this: http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/43475#DownloadId=116534 the are a sapmle with it:)

Answer (score 0):

Download the Ajax Control Toolkit from www.ASP.net/ajax

Comment: It's not the control tool kit I need that doens't setup my web application to be ajaxed that just gives me the controls